# I need to format XP

Tags: format, windows-xp

I wish to format the hard drive and install Ubuntu on a machine with XP installed. I am getting a prompt telling me that a volume is in use and then the forced unmount is failing. How can I get rid of XP please?

Comment: How are you trying to format your drive? Are you using an Ubuntu LiveCD? Note that you can simply install on top of an XP installation.

Answer (score 2):

You download the ubuntu image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download and make a bootable cd with it.Put the cd inside the drive and restart the pc and select "boot from cd" from BIOS and wait it to load. You can try ubuntu without installing and if you prefer select "install" and follow the simple installation process.Ubuntu allows you to install it as "one and only OS" or "along with XP".

Answer (score 0):

Did the options menu come during the installation?It would show you some options to zero out data on the disk and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

The file system seems to be damaged. Boot into Windows, run disk repair, reboot **twice**, and try again.
If it still doesn't work, backup your data, format the hard drive, and install Ubuntu.